# Facing Authorization issue with Gsuite API

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-workspace

I want to create user using Google API to my domain. I am facing authorization issue with the following code. please suggest me with any code sample if you have. I am providing my code below Please help me out.

```
            string[] Scopes = { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser };
            string ApplicationName = "App Name";
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
               new FileStream(Server.MapPath("..\\") + credentials.json",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = Server.MapPath("..\\") + "token.json";

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Directory API service.
            var service = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


            UsersResource usersResource = new UsersResource(service);


            Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User user = new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User();
            UserName name = new UserName();
            name.FamilyName = register.ClientName;
            name.GivenName = register.ClientName;
            user.Name = name;
            user.Password = Password;
            user.PrimaryEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CompanyEmailID"].ToString();

            var r = usersResource.Insert(user);
            r.Execute();
```

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding the issue you are having?

Comment: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=810703269472-05ub8m1uihch0skg1urafio18bl053i0.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A55579%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadmin.directory.user" for authorization. See inner exception for details.